# Adobe Edge Symbol Relative Size

Tags: symbols, adobe-edge

is there a way for a Symbol in Adobe Edge to be sized with percentage values?
Unfortunately I see the toggle disabled but I'd really need to have a symbol with relative dimensions.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double click on the symbol to edit it, you can set the width and height to be percentage. You cannot change this from the stage directly, since you are editing a symbol instance (that is why it's disabled).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you do want to be able to change the size from the main stage, double click the symbol to open it, and change the `Instance` property from `Scale` to `Resize`.

Now the symbol will be able to be editable via percentages from the main stage.